# KVO Binding failing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, key-value-observing

This bug has me truly frustrated. I am using KVO as follows:

```
dynamic var product: NSNumber? {
    get {
        return (defaults.objectForKey("product") != nil ? defaults.integerForKey("product") : nil)
    }
    set(newValue) {
        if newValue != product {
            willChangeValueForKey("product")
            if let value = newValue {
                defaults.setInteger(value.integerValue, forKey: "product")
            } else {
                defaults.removeObjectForKey("product")
            }
            didChangeValueForKey("product")
            reader.product = newValue?.integerValue
            refresh()
        }
    }
}

override class func automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Another object modifies the property as follows;

```
    info.product = NSNumber(short: prodId)
```

When called, the result is the following error;

```
    Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0x0)
```

And stack trace:

```
#0  0x37c4cf66 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x2acca772 in NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread ()
#2  0x2acbae3c in NSKeyValueWillChange ()
#3  0x2aca7c04 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] ()
#4  0x2acdafc0 in _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify ()
#5  0x002a3c44 in Module.MyView.pickerView (Module.MyView)(ObjectiveC.UIPickerView, didSelectRow : Swift.Int, inComponent : Swift.Int) -> () at /<***>/MyView.swift:122
```

Now, I've set breakpoints and prints and determined that `NSKeyValueWillChange` is called before the var setter code is called, so it appears that this is not being used in the same way as in Objective C, that the message for `NSKeyValueWillChange` is being sent before the the setter is being called. In Objective C the setter had to manually call `willChangeValueForKey("product")`. Anybody have any idea what is happening?

On a side note, the following s the code where the crash occurs. The error occurs on the third line, I am guessing that r9 being 0x0 has something to do with it.

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x37c4cf60:  cbz    r0, 0x37c4cf9e            ; objc_msgSend + 62
0x37c4cf62:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x37c4cf66:  ldrh.w r12, [r9, #12]
0x37c4cf6a:  ldr.w  r9, [r9, #8]
0x37c4cf6e:  and.w  r12, r12, r1
0x37c4cf72:  add.w  r9, r9, r12, lsl #3
0x37c4cf76:  ldr.w  r12, [r9]
0x37c4cf7a:  teq.w  r12, r1
0x37c4cf7e:  bne    0x37c4cf86                ; objc_msgSend + 38
0x37c4cf80:  ldr.w  r12, [r9, #4]
0x37c4cf84:  bx     r12
0x37c4cf86:  cmp.w  r12, #0x1
0x37c4cf8a:  blo    0x37c4cf98                ; objc_msgSend + 56
0x37c4cf8c:  it     eq
0x37c4cf8e:  ldreq.w r9, [r9, #4]
0x37c4cf92:  ldr    r12, [r9, #8]!
0x37c4cf96:  b      0x37c4cf7a                ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x37c4cf98:  ldr.w  r9, [r0]
0x37c4cf9c:  b      0x37c4d1e0                ; _objc_msgSend_uncached
0x37c4cf9e:  mov.w  r1, #0x0
0x37c4cfa2:  bx     lr
```

Comment: I'd suggest that `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` call `super` for any property for which you're not overriding the behavior. Also, have you actually registered an observer for this property? When I do, I see two sets of notifications (which makes sense, because there's the automatically generated notification and the one you're sending manually).

Comment: BTW, what is `reader` and what does `refresh()` do?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure to call **didChangeValueForKey:** and **willChangeValueForKey:**. You dont need to override getter and setter to just trigger the KVO notification. I dont know the extact implementation but looking at your class, if the info class had to trigger the notification on the product change, then it would look like this,

```
 class MyInfoClass {
  var product: NSNumber?{
      willSet{
        self.willChangeValueForKey("product")
      }
      didSet{
        self.didChangeValueForKey("product")
      }
    }

  override class func automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
    if key == "product"{
      return true
    }else{
      return automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key)
    }
  }
}
```

But if you wish to use dynamic, then you dont need to override the kvo method **automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:** and do not need to trigger **willChangeValueForKey:** and **didChangeValueForKey:**. Please mind it that you class should be a subclass of NSObject. In that case your class would simply look like this,

```
class MyInfoClass:NSObject{
  dynamic var product: NSNumber?
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but you've made one of the mistakes that I initially made; `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` returns true by default, so it should be returning `false` for "product". Also `willSet` and `didSet` cannot be used with a mutator method… and the code still crashes on the message send. However, this is still useful as it helps me diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem (perhaps because I don't have `reader` object or `refresh()` function), but your code is generating two (nested) KVN for `product`. If `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` returns `true` (which means that the `product` KVN will happen automatically), one shouldn't be manually posting KVN for that property.

There are two options:

1. You can turn off automatic KVN for `product` and do it yourself:

   ```
   dynamic var product: NSNumber? {
       get {
           return defaults.objectForKey("product") as? NSNumber
       }
       set {
           if newValue != product {
               willChangeValueForKey("product")
               if let value = newValue {
                   defaults.setInteger(value.integerValue, forKey: "product")
               } else {
                   defaults.removeObjectForKey("product")
               }
               didChangeValueForKey("product")
               // reader.product = newValue?.integerValue
               // refresh()
           }
       }
   }

   override class func automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
       if key == "product" {
           return false
       }
       return super.automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key)   // prudent to call super rather than just returning `true`
   }
   ```
2. You can leave automatic KVN on, and then don't do it yourself:

   ```
   dynamic var product: NSNumber? {
       get {
           return defaults.objectForKey("product") as? NSNumber
       }
       set {
           if newValue != product {
               if let value = newValue {
                   defaults.setInteger(value.integerValue, forKey: "product")
               } else {
                   defaults.removeObjectForKey("product")
               }
               // reader.product = newValue?.integerValue
               // refresh()
           }
       }
   }

   // we don't need this at all if all we're going to do is to return the super value
   //
   // override class func automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
   //     return super.automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey(key)
   // }
   ```

Comment: Well spotted. I didn't think that would be an issue. However, this isn't the complete solution, because if I remove the `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` statements the crash still occurs. I've seen this same error posted ('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289728/swift-bindings-kvo-kvc-issue') but for much simpler code, and it does appear that there might be an error in the automatically generated messages.

Comment: From the documentation, I had assumed that `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` returned `false` by default, but I have confirmed that `true` is the default. When I had it return `false` as you suggested, I got a new error. The error now occurs in `willChangeValueForKey`, but now it is happening *inside* my mutator method, not in automatically generated code.

Comment: The stack trace is below, and is interesting; 

#0 0x3831bc8c in OSAtomicCompareAndSwapIntBarrier$VARIANT$mp ()
#1 0x37c43c76 in realizeClass(objc_class*) ()
#2 0x37c46fe4 in lookUpImpOrForward ()
#3 0x37c46f3e in _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 ()
#4 0x37c4d1f8 in _objc_msgSend_uncached ()
#5 0x2acca772 in NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread ()
#6 0x2acbae3c in NSKeyValueWillChange ()
#7 0x2aca7c04 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] ()

Comment: My code above worked for me (fixed the dual notifications of your original code, doesn't crash in my app), so I wonder if the problem may rest elsewhere? For example, are you 100% sure that neither the observer nor the observed object are deallocated? I'd put `deinit` methods on both and make sure there isn't something untowards going on.

Comment: Check the other answer I posted. The problem was an `MKAnnotationView` that had moved out of view. The object was cached, and so when messages were issued that object wasn't available. I suspect the same will happen with table cells and collection cells. However, all this also gave me a lot of insights and far more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** While this solution worked initially, later changes made it ineffective.

I just found a solution, and to me it seems really dumb. All I had to do was move the `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` method calls like so;

```
dynamic var product: NSNumber? {
    get {
        return (defaults.objectForKey("product") != nil ? defaults.integerForKey("product") : nil)
    }
    set(newValue) {
        willChangeValueForKey("product")
        if newValue != product {
            if let value = newValue {
                defaults.setInteger(value.integerValue, forKey: "product")
            } else {
                defaults.removeObjectForKey("product")
            }
            reader.product = newValue?.integerValue
            refresh()
        }
        didChangeValueForKey("product")
    }
}
```

At a guess, I'd say the implementation is being smart. If it doesn't see the call to `willChangeValueForKey` as the first thing in the mutator method, it calls it before entering the mutator, and screws up the call. Having moved these calls, the code now doesn't make those default calls, and it all works correctly.

That sounds both very smart and very dumb. Other opinions?

Comment: I don't see how this edit would change the behavior. All this does is to issue more redundant change notifications even when the value is unchanged.

Comment: Yes, that true; I don't see how it would change it either, but it did. I suspect as I said before that the code must explicitly look for a `willChangeValueForKey` in the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try another approach.

```
dynamic var product: NSNumber? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("product") as? NSNumber

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    switch keyPath {
    case "product":
        if let value = product {
            defaults.setInteger(value.integerValue, forKey: "product")
        } else {
            defaults.removeObjectForKey("product")
        }

    default:
        break
    }
}

init() {
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "product", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.allZeros, context: nil)
}

deinit {
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "product")
}
```

The result of this change was exactly the same; the code crashes during message dispatch. The only advantage is that I think this is cleaner code than the original.

Comment: Just a note: I would avoid to use "dynamic" property modifier, because it forces to use Objective C Runtime and we don't want this in Swift :) The refactoring in the future will have to probably happen ..

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Apologies to everbody, the problem was not in the code I presented, it was in an observer.

The problem was that one of my observers was a custom `MKAnnotaionView`, and it was observing the `product` value. However, when an annotation left the current map view, the annoationView was removed from the map and cached. When the `willChangeValueForKey` method was triggered, it tried to reach the annotationView and failed, triggering the crash.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    Static.info.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "product", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.allZeros, context: nil)
}

deinit {
    Static.info.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "product")
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    switch keyPath {
    case "product":
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            self.refreshText()
            self.refreshImages()
        }

    default:
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}

override var annotation: MKAnnotation! {
    get {
        return super.annotation
    }
    set(newAnnotation) {
        super.annotation = newAnnotation
        if let annot = newAnnotation as? MyAnnotation {
            self.refreshText()
            self.refreshImages()
        }
    }
}
```

The original code set up the observer in `init` and removed it in `deinit`. Here is a new code fragment that works correctly.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
}

deinit {
    if annotation != nil {
        Static.info.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "product")
    }
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    switch keyPath {
    case "product":
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            self.refreshText()
            self.refreshImages()
        }

    default:
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}

override var annotation: MKAnnotation! {
    get {
        return super.annotation
    }
    set(newAnnotation) {
        if annotation != nil {
            Static.info.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "product")
        }
        super.annotation = newAnnotation
        if let annot = newAnnotation as? MyAnnotation {
            Static.info.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "product", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.allZeros, context: nil)
            self.refreshText()
            self.refreshImages()
        }
    }
}
```

By adding and removing the observer in the annotation mutator, the view is never updated while it is cached, preventing the bug from occurring.